# What would be the best method to print certain keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a project that requires me to create a country:capital spreadsheet, like United states | D.C. in excel. The problem is that some keys are continents and territories, which would not have a capital. How would I print only the countries?

```
    for ctry in countries:
        print(f'{ctry["name"]:30}{ctry["capitalCity"]}')
```

results in:

```
        Middle East & North Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)
        Tonga                         Nuku'alofa
        South Asia (IDA & IBRD)       
        Sub-Saharan Africa (IDA & IBRD countries)
        Trinidad and Tobago           Port-of-Spain
```

**Edit:** After reading the comments, I realized that I did not include enough information, so I will try to fill in those gaps here. I got the dictionary of countries from the World Bank API (http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country?format=json&per_page=400), and that list also included continents and territories. I wrote an if statement, which said,

```
     if ctry['capitalCity'] in ctry:
        print(f'{ctry["name"]:20}{ctry["capitalCity"]}')
    else:
        print('not working')
```

My thought process here was that if I used 'in', the if statement would be able to print only the keys with a corresponding value, but that didn't work, so I came here. Sorry about the lack of information, but thanks for all of your advice.

Comment: Maybe check `if` `ctry["capitalCity"]` before printing?

Comment: If it's a country:capital spreadsheet, why do you have things that aren't countries in it?

Comment: Most of all, we can't give you a solid answer, because you haven't specified the problem sufficiently.  What in your dictionary can differentiate a country from something else?  What have you tried to test for that in your code?  If it's merely a matter of checking for a capital, you should have done that before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `countries` is a list of dictionaries with both countries, continents, and territories, and the continents and territories don't have a 'capitalCity' element (or one that resolves to False, like None):

```py
actual_countries = [c for c in countries if c.get('capitalCity')]
```

Now everything in actual_countries is one with a capitalCity element.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you tell me what concept this is? I started learning Python a few months ago and I have not come across anything like this.

Comment: Are you asking about list comprehensions? Python lets you construct lists in handy one-liners like this. It's equivalent to writing a for loop with an if statement normally. There are lots of resources on this: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 0):

From your question -> *some keys are continents and territories, which would not have a capital.*

which means your countries might look like this, where the continents either have empty capitalCity (eg. Asia) , None capitalCity (eg. Australia) or capitalCity key is not present (eg. North America) either.

So based on above assumption having all 3(empty, None, no-key) cases in below list countries.

```
countries = [{'name':'India','capitalCity':'New Delhi'},{'name':'US','capitalCity':'Washington'},{'name':'Australia','capitalCity':None},{'name':'Albania','capitalCity': 'Tirana'},{'name':'Algeria','capitalCity':'Algiers'}, {'name':'Angola', 'capitalCity': 'Luanda'},{'name':'Asia','capitalCity': ''}, {'name':'North America'}]
```

You can try this below code to skip continents/territories.

```
for ctry in countries:
    if ctry.get('capitalCity'):
        print(f'{ctry["name"]:30}{ctry["capitalCity"]}')
```

---